# IBM.XMS ExceptionListener not firing

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using IBM.XMS 2.0.0.5 and MQ Client 7.0.1.5 and have created a connection, set the exception listener, started the connection and started listening for messages using a message listener. This works fine, except that the `ExceptionListener` does not fire when I disable the network connection. Instead I get an unhandled socket exception.

I have gone back to the example given on the IBM site and recreated the error:

If I disable the network connetion I get the unhandled socket exception and the exceptionListener does not get fired.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using IBM.XMS;

public class Sample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XMSFactoryFactory factoryFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);

        IConnectionFactory connectionFactory = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "**********");
        connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "*****");
        connectionFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
        connectionFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "*********");

        //
        // Create the connection and register an exception listener
        //

        IConnection connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        connection.ExceptionListener = new ExceptionListener(OnException);

        ISession session = connection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
        IDestination queue = session.CreateQueue("queue://***********");

        //
        // Create the consumer and register an async message listener
        //

        IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(queue);
        consumer.MessageListener = new MessageListener(OnMessage);

        connection.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for messages....");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    static void OnMessage(IMessage msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    static void OnException(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on your setup?  Are you connecting to a remote or local queue manager?

Comment: I am connecting to a remote queue manager. I am developing this on Windows XP, using MQ client 7.0.1.5 and Message Service Client for .NET 2.0.0.5.

Answer (score 6):

I'll put the answer up in the hope that it saves someone the time it wasted for me.

You need to use an unmanaged client connection in order to connect up an exception listener to your connection.

connectionFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED);

Answer (score -1):

If it's just worked in Unmanaged mode, then it's a bug at XMS .NET v2.0.0.5. It should work in Managed mode also (XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_MANAGED). Please move to the latest fix pack and test again.